# State from API in React

Tags: reactjs, api, components, state

I'm carrying out a project that can modify the price of a product (retrieved from a fake API) then by clicking on a button I update by calculating the 20% VAT. I encounter a problem, I would like to have a price state and that in this state, it is the value of my entry namely {listProduct.price}, so that the price of my API is displayed initially in the input ( namely $ 105.95 for the first article, ...) but it does not work.

you will first find the code of the productsDetails part where it displays the products page and the products code which retrieves the data from the API

If you have any solutions I'm interested, thanks in advance. (sorry, I'm new to React, I'm still struggling with all of these concepts)

ProductsDetails

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../css/ProductsDetails.css'
import {AiOutlineArrowLeft} from "react-icons/ai";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'


export default class ProductsDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {id: this.props.match.params.id, price: };
    }
    updatePrice = (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        this.setState({
            price: e.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        const {location: {state: {listProduct}}} = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="products__details">
                <Link to="/"><AiOutlineArrowLeft className="nav__arrow" /></Link>
                <h1 className="details__title">{listProduct.title}</h1>
                <div className="details__align--desk">
                    <div className="details__img">
                    <img className="product__img" src={listProduct.image} alt="Affichage du produit"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="products__align--desk">
                        <h2 className="product__title">Description</h2>
                        <p className="product__description">{listProduct.description}</p>
                        <h2 className="product__title">Price</h2>
                        <form className="form__price">
                            <input className="input__price" type="text" value={listProduct.price} onChange={this.updatePrice} />
                            <p>Price (including VAT): {Math.round((listProduct.price + listProduct.price * 0.2)*100) /100} €</p>
                            <br/>
                            <input className="btn__update" type="submit" value="Update product" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div className="category__align--desk">
                        <h2 className="product__title">Category</h2>
                        <p className="product__category">{listProduct.category}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    } 
}
```

Products

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../css/Products.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import './ProductsDetails'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

export default class Products extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {productsData: []};
    }
      componentDidMount = () => {
        axios.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/products?limit=7')
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data)
          this.setState ({
            productsData: res.data
          })
        })
      }
    render() {
        const listsProducts = this.state.productsData.map(listProduct => {
            return <tbody className="products__body">
                    <tr>
                        <td> <Link to={{pathname: "/products-details/" + listProduct.id,state: {listProduct}}}>{listProduct.title}</Link></td>
                        <td className="products__category">{listProduct.category}</td>
                        <td>{listProduct.price}</td>
                        <td>{Math.round((listProduct.price + listProduct.price * 0.2)*100) /100}</td>
                    </tr> 
              </tbody>
          })
        return (
            <main className="products">
                <h1 className="products__title">Products management</h1>
                <table cellSpacing="0">
                <thead className="products__head">
                    <tr>
                    <th className="table--title">Product name</th>
                    <th className="table--title">Category</th>
                    <th className="table--title">Price</th>
                    <th className="table--title">Price (including VAT)</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                  {listsProducts}
                </table>
            </main>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I copy/pasted your code into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/state-from-api-in-react-6hfvn) and it runs without issue (after providing valid initial `price` state in `ProductDetails. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, the issue is that I cannot put in my state the initial price of listProduct.price what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to display some data in one component and update *that* data from another then the solution here is to [Lift State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Move the products state and data fetching to a common ancestor to both `ProductsDetails` and `Products` components.

Suggestions:

1. Declare `productsData`, data fetching, and `updatePrice` handler in parent component.

   ```
   function App() {
     const [productsData, setProductsData] = useState([]);

     useEffect(() => {
       axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products?limit=7").then((res) => {
         console.log(res.data);
         setProductsData(res.data);
       });
     }, []);

     const updatePrice = (id, price) => {
       setProductsData((productsData) =>
         productsData.map((product) =>
           product.id === Number(id)
             ? {
                 ...product,
                 price: Number(price)
               }
             : product
         )
       );
     };

     return (
       <div className="App">
         <Router>
           <Switch>
             <Route
               path="/products-details/:id"
               render={(props) => (
                 <ProductsDetails
                   products={productsData}
                   updatePrice={updatePrice}
                   {...props}
                 />
               )}
             />
             <Route path="/">
               <Products products={productsData} />
             </Route>
           </Switch>
         </Router>
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```
2. Update `Products` to consume a `products` prop from the parent.

   ```
   class Products extends Component {
     render() {
       const listsProducts = this.props.products.map((listProduct) => {
         return (
           <tbody className="products__body" key={listProduct.id}>
             <tr>
               <td>
                 {" "}
                 <Link
                   to={{
                     pathname: "/products-details/" + listProduct.id
                   }}
                 >
                   {listProduct.title}
                 </Link>
               </td>
               <td className="products__category">{listProduct.category}</td>
               <td>{Number(listProduct.price).toFixed(2)}</td>
               <td>
                 {Number(listProduct.price * 1.2).toFixed(2)} €
               </td>
             </tr>
           </tbody>
         );
       });

       return (
         <main className="products">
           <h1 className="products__title">Products management</h1>
           <table cellSpacing="0">
             <thead className="products__head">
               <tr>
                 <th className="table--title">Product name</th>
                 <th className="table--title">Category</th>
                 <th className="table--title">Price</th>
                 <th className="table--title">Price (including VAT)</th>
               </tr>
             </thead>
             {listsProducts}
           </table>
         </main>
       );
     }
   }
   ```
3. Update `ProductsDetails` to consume both a `products` and `updatePrice` callback prop. Create a `submitHandler` for the form to update the price. For the input you'll want to use the `defaultValue` prop since you want to provide an initial value but ***not*** immediately change the original data.

   ```
   class ProductsDetails extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = { id: this.props.match.params.id, price: 0 };
     }

     updatePrice = (e) => {
       console.log(e);
       this.setState({
         price: e.target.value
       });
     };

     submitHandler = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
       const {
         match: {
           params: { id }
         }
       } = this.props;
       this.props.updatePrice(id, this.state.price);
     };

     render() {
       const {
         match: {
           params: { id }
         },
         products
       } = this.props;

       const listProduct = products.find((product) => product.id === Number(id));

       return (
         <div className="products__details">
           <Link to="/">
             <AiOutlineArrowLeft className="nav__arrow" />
           </Link>
           <h1 className="details__title">{listProduct.title}</h1>
           <div className="details__align--desk">
             <div className="details__img">
               <img
                 className="product__img"
                 src={listProduct.image}
                 alt="Affichage du produit"
               />
             </div>
             <div className="products__align--desk">
               <h2 className="product__title">Description</h2>
               <p className="product__description">{listProduct.description}</p>
               <h2 className="product__title">Price</h2>
               <form className="form__price" onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                 <input
                   className="input__price"
                   type="text"
                   defaultValue={Number(listProduct.price).toFixed(2)}
                   onChange={this.updatePrice}
                 />
                 <p>
                   Price (including VAT):{" "}
                   {Number(listProduct.price * 1.2).toFixed(2)} €
                 </p>
                 <br />
                 <input
                   className="btn__update"
                   type="submit"
                   value="Update product"
                 />
               </form>
             </div>
             <div className="category__align--desk">
               <h2 className="product__title">Category</h2>
               <p className="product__category">{listProduct.category}</p>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       );
     }
   }
   ```

[image: Edit state-from-api-in-react]

Comment: Oh thank you very much !! This is exactly what I wanted to produce!

Comment: @RitalCharmant Sorry, I should have called out the type differences between the input's value when updating state, it will be a string versus a number, and similarly with the product id, it's a number in the product object, but the `id` route param will be a string. This is why sometimes the `id` and `e.target.value` are run through a `Number` function so value types are consistent.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have one last question, how could I have known that this is how it should be done? Is it written somewhere? Because I tried to look for information but I did not find

Comment: @RitalCharmant That's a good question. I did link to the official docs about lifting state up. Generally you want to limit the scope of variables as much as possible, finding the point between pushing state/etc down the hierarchy to limit the scope more, and components lifting it up to the closets common ancestor so all components that need it can access it. Along with lifting state up you have the React [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) available. Beyond this you'll find global state management libraries like Redux/Mobx where components "subscribe" to the app "state".

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations and for your time spent explaining myself, I understand better now, even if I still have to work on it to fully assimilate. Can you explain to me this line of code that I have trouble understanding? I know it's a ternary operator but what are the three dots for?
 
`const updatePrice = (id, price) => {setProductsData((productsData) => productsData.map((product) => product.id === Number(id) ? {...product,price: Number(price)}: product));};`

Comment: @RitalCharmant The `...` is called the [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). It used to copy the properties of the `product` object into a new object reference since you're updating the `price` property. React reconciliation works by using object reference equality. If on the next render an object reference still refers to the same object as the previous render then React bails on rerendering it, and conversely, if the object reference has changed then React assumes the value possibly changed and rerenders.

Comment: Thank you very much, yes it is much clearer now. Sorry to bother you again, but I have another problem I put a `localStorage` to my` submitHandler` function so that when I press the button it keeps in mind the saved price except when I press the button the price changes well and it is kept in the console in the localStorage but when I reload the page I have an error message which appears telling me: `×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`
I do not understand why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232370/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-ritalcharmant).